# Importing Excel data to compare data in Salesforce

Tags: excel, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a question regarding Excel and Salesforce.

I have an excel file with fields (like license expiration date) that matches a field type in my Salesforce org.

Is it possible to create a flow or something, that can compare specific fields from the excel ark and the Salesforce data and fill out the field in SF if it is = NULL and/or update if they are not EQUAL to each other?

The field exists within the opportunity object that has a unique id in the URL. This unique ID will also be placed in the excel so that it is comparable with SF's opportunities.

I hope this makes sense.

:D

Thank you!

I have tried to search trailblazer for an answer. But cannot seem to find one.